# "screen" process closes out of the blue

Tags: osx, gnu-screen

I spawned 4 screen processes with the following command (one after the other):

```
screen ./"executeable"
```

Logging back into the server I run the program on at a later time only showed 3 processes remaining (with `screen -r`). How can I find out what is going wrong?
The error is reproduceable and I think its because of my program, but as screen just closes I cannot be sure..

Comment: So one of the instances of the program exited. So what? This has nothing to do with Screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `screen` option `-L`, you can switch on logging of the output to files named `screenlog.n` with `n` the index of the window.

The problem is that one of your programs terminates, either normally, or by an error.
If the program exits, screen will close the window, that's normal.

If the program exits on an error, it may show a message before exiting, which would be shown in the log file when using `screen -L ...` to start.

If the program does not write any messaged before it exits, look for a way to make it write more messages, for example an option like `-v`/`--verbose` for verbose output, or `--debug` for debug output.